# Android - Invalid Resource Directory Name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tentei de tudo pesquisando na internet, vi várias respostas sobre dar Clean Project, renomear, atualizar IDE e nada funcionou. Ainda continua dando o seguinte problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só quero organizar melhor os arquivos de layout adicionando uma pasta para separa-los. Entretanto está dando este erro e não encontrei solução

Answer (score 3):

As pastas de uma aplicação Android seguem uma estrutura e nomes de pastas bem definida.

Por padrão os *resources* do tipo *layout* deverão ser colocados na pasta

***path_do_projecto\app\src\main\res\layout***

No seu caso o que está mal é, além de ter ***..\app\src\main\res\layouts***(layouts em vez de layout), tem ainda outra pasta ***layout-tuto***.

Para resolver

- renomeie a pasta ***layouts*** para **layout***.
- passe o conteúdo da pasta ***layout-tuto*** para a ***layout***.
- elimine a pasta ***layout-tuto***.

No entanto é possível ter outras pastas de *resources*. Elas devem ser configuradas no arquivo *build.gradle* através de `sourceSets` usando a propriedade `res.srcDirs`.

```
android{

    ....
    ....
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs += ['src/main/res2']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas se eu fizer isso, como vou obter os layouts organizados por pasta? Tudo em uma pasta só ficará bem dificil para se localizar quando o projeto ficar maior

Comment: Mas a arquitetura é essa mesma. Se o aplicativo está tão grande assim, você pode modularizá-lo e configurar as dependências entre eles no grade. Assim você teria uma pasta por módulo com as classes, activities, layouts, etc em cada uma delas.

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz:

> Nome do diretório de recursos inválido

Você criou um diretório, `layout-tuto`, dentro de um outro diretório, `layouts`, que não é reconhecido pelo SDK do Android, por fim, logo é lançado o erro na sua IDE. Para resolver o problema, você deve alterar o nome do diretório `layouts` para `layout` como recomendado na documentação. Você pode melhorar e organizar sua estrutura, através do nome de seus *layouts*.

Veja em [Fornecimento de recursos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) as recomendações válidas para nomes de diretórios.